# Limitations of Grep

Tags: grep

When I grep on a log file , the matched patterns are truncated to 2048 characters.

Eg: grep 'txn-id-111111' transactions.log gives

*2015-12-18 (txn-id-111111) EmployeeInformation[AssociateDetails[empId=161223,empname=JohnSmith],AssociateAddress[street1 =1074 NY boulevard]..........................empBranch=N*

The object is printed only until 2048 characters.

Is there a way to retrieve the complete line without getting truncated?

FYI..I'm using using super putty.

Comment: Are you sure the line actually contains the full contents and it isn't split? Is it always 2048 characters? No matter what line you match?

Comment: yes.. When I normally check in the log in a text editor, I see the complete information as
2015-12-18 (txn-id-111111) EmployeeInformation[AssociateDetails[empId=161223,empname=JohnSmith],AssociateAddress[street1 =1074 NY boulevard]..........................empBranch=NewYork,empState=NewYork,empCountry=USA]

There a re no splits and is always 2048 chacters